# OutputStream - Access Denied in AppData/Roaming

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream

I'm trying to copy a file into C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\mods using Input/Output Stream and I am getting this errpr: 
FileStreamsTest: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\mods (Access is denied)

Whats strange is that I am able to run another bit of code that actually makes the mods folder and downloads a file into it. Here is the input/output stream:

```
String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
                   File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                   String fullPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                   String filename = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
                   String dest = ("C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft 
\\mods\\");

                   try {
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fullPath);
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dest);
                    int c;

                    while ((c = fis.read()) != -1) {
                       fos.write(c);
                    }

                    fis.close();
                    fos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    System.err.println("FileStreamsTest: " + e1);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    System.err.println("FileStreamsTest: " + e1);
                }
```

And if you want to take a look, heres the code where I make the folder and download a file into it.

Folder Create:

```
String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
        String part1 = "C:\\Users\\";
        String part2 = "\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\mods\\";
          File theDir = new File(part1 + username + part2);

          // if the directory does not exist, create it
          if (!theDir.exists()) {
            System.out.println("creating directory: " + part1 + username + part2);
            boolean result = false;

            try{
                theDir.mkdir();
                result = true;
             } catch(SecurityException se){
                //handle it
             }        
             if(result) {    
               System.out.println("DIR created");  
             }
          }
```

File Download:

```
tmi.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            URL website;
            try {
                website = new URL("http://marglyph.s3.amazonaws.com
/TooManyItems2014_07_15_1.7.10_Forge.jar");
                ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\" + username +  
"\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\mods\\TooManyItems2014_07_15_1.7.10_Forge.jar");
                fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);


            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this one out, and thought I would share for people who might run into this issue. The problem was, when I entered the destination, I didn't enter the name of the file. I had the variable set up, so in the end, my outputstream looked like.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dest + filename);
```

And the variables were:

```
String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
                   File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                   String fullPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                   String filename = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
                   String dest = ("C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft
                   \\mods\\");
```